# App Store Error: "Failed to verify the preflight file. It is not signed by Apple."

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I recently released an OS X app to the Mac AppStore (after successful App Review performed by Apple). If I try to install this App via the AppStore I end up with this error directly shown after pressing the install button (even before any actual download activity):

```
“App Store Error: Failed to verify the preflight file. It is not signed by Apple.”
```

I found a generic hint/some potential issues related to this error message with the Keychain preferences:
http://manytricks.com/blog/?p=3339

Changing those settings (even deactivated for OCSP and CRL) did not solve my issue. I also reproduced this issue on a blank system without this app ever been installed to. I could start the application from the uploaded xcarchive package without any problem and also the check process on Xcode/iTunesConnect did not reveal any problems.

This is the corresponding system console log:

```
16.02.16 18:07:39,597 storedownloadd[458]:
*** Assertion failure in -[CheckPreflightOperation verifyDistributionAtURL:allowsDevSign:allowsUnsigned:osVersionToBeInstalled:error:distributionController:], /SourceCache/Commerce/Commerce-376.29/CommerceKit/CheckPreflightOperation.m:307
```

Comment: are you able to install other apps from the app store? my guess is an issue on Apple's end, as i'm getting the same error when trying to update only one app from the app store, all other apps have updated just fine.

Comment: Popping up all over the place for our customers as well. Possibly related to the certificate update on Apple's server on Feb 14

Comment: I agree that this seems to be not an issue for all Apps (obviously) or sepcific to my systems I tried; other apps can be installed on such without this issue. The problematic App was build, signed an uploaded on the 13th of February; another App build, signed an uploaded the day before works fine.